# Trouble installing .NET 3.5 in Windows 10

Tags: .net

I am having trouble installing .NET framework 3.5 in windows 10 OS.

When I try to install .NET 3.5, it is not downloading required files from the server and says "Windows couldn't complete the required changes" with an error code

I tried using windows 8 but it does work well with that.

It would be a great help if someone help me out with the proper resolution.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170203-OfflineInstallationOfNet35InWindows10.html

Comment: It works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Update group policy can disable the update. If this is the case:

- Go into RegEdit and navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU folder.
- Double-click on UseWUServer and change the value to 0.
- Try to install .NET 3.5 from the Turn Windows Features on and off dialog or through the .NET 3.5 installer (dotnetfx35.exe) provided by Microsoft.

Works for Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Don't forget to turn back the value of UseWUServer to 1 once you install the framework.